# Concatenated data in one cell; delete entire row when 1 piece of info is not present

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, autofilter

I run a report that displays a list of employees with all the information associated with their employment record. One of the things on there is a concatenated list of all their Employee Roles, with a Valid To and From date. For example, if the list of possible Roles is as follows:

- Role 1
- Role 1 – trainer
- Role 2
- Role 2 – trainer
- Role 3
- Role 3 – trainer
- Trainee employee
- Former employee
- Probationary employee

And there’s an employee who is checked off as Role 1, Role 1 – trainer, Role 2, and they used to be Role 3, the information will display in one cell as the following:

- Role 1 – 1/1/2020 to N/A;Role 1 – trainer – 1/1/2020;Role 2 –
  1/1/2020 to N/A;Role 3 – 1/1/2020 to 28/2/2020

For the report I’m using, I only want to be able to see a list of Active employees in Role 1 (so, not including people who have retired from Role 1 but are still active in other Roles).

I have the following piece of code which allows me to remove from the list anyone does not have Role 1 in their record:

```
Sub deleteifnotR1 ()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Record")

    lastRow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("E1:E" & lastRow)

    'filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Role 1*"
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If lr > 1 Then
         Range("D2:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it will still leave me with a list of Former employees, and active employees who may have retired from Role 1, but are still Role 3 etc.

In thinking about how to fix this, I’ve had two ideas – firstly, is it possible to un-concatenate this data? For example, to insert new columns across the top with all the different possible roles, and then have a macro that identifies when someone has “Role 1 – trainer” in their record and move that data over to the correct column? Then I could use a variation of the code above to delete anyone who doesn’t have “N/A” in the Role 1 column.

Alternatively, is it possible to amend the following line:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Role 1*"
```

To search in some way for “Role 1 – *ANY DATE* to N/A”? This would filter out both former employees, and employees who have retired from Role 1 but nothing else.

(Ideally I would just rework the report rather than having to fix it after the fact, but I don’t have access to that part of our system, and the people that do aren’t willing to do any development on it).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use more inner-wildcards within `AutoFilter`. But maybe try to utilize `Like` operator or maybe more flexibile; regular expressions.

Try something like:

```
Sub deleteifnotR1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Record")
    lastRow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\b[rR]ole 1 - \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} to N\/A\b"
        .Global = True
        For x = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            If Not .Test(ws.Cells(x, 5).Value) Then
                ws.Cells(x, 5).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next x
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The pattern used is better visualized like:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

As you can see it allows for both "role 1" and "Role 1" and does allow for dates written like "1/1/2020" or "10/10/2020".

If you got tons of data a better/faster approach would be to do this in memory through arrays. Hopefully this gets you started.

> **Note:** You have currently used dash instead of a hyphen after "Role 1 ".

Comment: Oh very interesting - I didn't even know this was possible. I just tried it out though, and it deletes everything except the top row. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: @LizH, yes. That's because the pattern is assuming a dash, I though by your sample you used dash isntead of hyphen. I changed it to hyphen. So please try again. If that still doesn't work copy past that character you are using inside the pattern instead of the hyphen.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. Wouldn't have got this solution without you.